# SSD's or HDD's in a LANcache?

Tags: raid, storage, cache, zfs, file-server

I am building a [LANcache](http://blog.multiplay.co.uk/2014/04/lancache-dynamically-caching-game-installs-at-lans-using-nginx/) for a lanparty that I'm organizing. We have about 80 visitors (pretty small LAN), but our uplink is limited to 100mb/s due to reasons and it's constantly saturated with game update/steam download traffic. A LANcache would probably help a lot. Our budget is not too large though.

At the moment I have composed a server with a 4Gbit/s network connection, and I want to fully saturate this connection with traffic, so that at least 4 people can download at gigabit speed simultaneously.

Now rests the question what kind of storage setup I need to serve 500MByte/s.
The LANcache in the link above uses 6 SSD's in RAIDZ, and one of the authors actually says that ['for this use HDD’s really don’t cut it'](http://blog.multiplay.co.uk/2014/04/lancache-dynamically-caching-game-installs-at-lans-using-nginx/#comment-231).

However, a friend of mine tells me that using SSD's is overkill, and that ZFS on 3 HDD's with compression on and an SSD as cache should be able to deliver 500MByte/s. I'm wondering if this is true though, because

- The data is probably already compressed, since it's packages of game data
- Many articles/forum posts on the internet which I sadly cannot link because not enough reputation quote RAIDZ performance with 3 HDD's to be around 280MByte/s, and one (who is incidentally using it for a LANcache) specifically mentions not being able to saturate a 4 gigabit link

So my actual questions are

- Is it useful in the first place to use ZFS? Everyone seems to use it but a cache doesn't seem to have a lot of use for reliability to me...
- Is it useful to use RAID-Z as opposed to RAID-0?
- In my situation, would it be better to use SSD's?
- Is it possible to deliver 500MByte/s with the HDD based setup mentioned?
- If using ZFS, what kind of CPU/memory specs would i need?

Comment: 500MB/sec with just three 7200 RPM drives is going to be difficult. But really, what you need to do is just set them up and benchmark them. If you can get 500MB/sec - great. Do not more. If not, then you need to reconsider. Honestly if this is just a temporary cache for a LAN party I'd just go RAID0. If you lose a drive, just take it off the network.